# Why won't Google show two pages from my site in the search results for the same keyword?

Tags: seo, google-search-console, keywords, search-results, pages

I have created two pages on my site for a one keyword. These pages have unique content. But their keyword is the same. But in Google search results, the new page replaces the previous page.

Why don't my two pages both show for one keyword? Each pages has unique content, but the keyword is that same. Both pages are accepted in search console. How can I get two of my pages in the search result for this keyword?

Answer (score 2):

There was a google statement, sorry cannot find link, that says they only list one page from a website in the top 10 results.

But I have seen multiple websites with multiple results on a single search term.

Best solution for you here to make sure both pages have good authority and make sure both have higher value-add than other pages in the search results.

Comment: Related article: [Google’s Matt Cutts: Domain Clustering To Change Again; Fewer Results From Same Domain](https://searchengineland.com/google-domain-clustering-change-159997)

Comment: Google uses the terms "host crowding" and "query deserves diversity (QDD)" for allowing or not allowing more than one link per website in the results.

Comment: Normally, when I see this the two results sort of compliment each other. For example, a web app/tool could be one result and then directly after it a "how to use this tool" sort of page.